# Error when trying to add quotation marks inside a Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm experiencing an error when I try to add a (") quotation mark in between 2 other quotation marks using a formula in google sheets, see below.

This is what I'm trying to achieve: `"Example1"` using this formula.`="""&A2&"""`where A2 = `Example 1`

If I use commas in between the quotation marks, it works. How can I make this work with the quotation marks?

Comment: `="""" & A2 & """"`?

Comment: as I can necver remember the rules between tools, my simple approach for these types of failure is just put the problem character in a cell (perhaps the column header) and refer to it with absolute syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need 4 of them:

```
=""""&A&""""
```

[image: 0]

---

also you can use `CHAR(34)`

```
=CHAR(34)&A2&CHAR(34)
```

[image: 0]